# Average a list of dictionaries based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, average

Having a list of n - dictionaries with a sample below:

```
n = [
  {'GB_written': '6.63',
  'avg_write_put': '81.45',
  'bGB_written': '4.78',
  'bbytes_written': '5129101312',
  'body_len': '512',
  'body_len_dist': '32',
  'bytes_written': '7118499840',
  'cache_size': '2.00',
  'device': 1,
  'documents': '1000000',
  'duration': '60',
  'engine': 2,
  'key_len': '32',
  'key_len_dist': '2',
  'read_ops': '31287.45',
  'read_us': '31.96',
  'reads': '1879063',
  'thread_reader': '1',
  'thread_writer': '1',
  'total_ops': '2885853',
  'write_amp': '9.4',
  'write_ops': '16763.61',
  'write_us': '59.65',
  'writes': '1006790',
  'written_perdoc': '4.97'},
  # more dictionaries
]
```

I am trying to average them out iterating out each dictionary, then each key with the function:

```
def prepare_data(data):
    avg  = {
        'engine' : 0,
        'device' : 0,
        'documents' : 0,
        'thread_reader': 0,
        'thread_writer' : 0,
        'cache_size' : 0,
        'key_len' : 0,
        'key_len_dist' : 0,
        'body_len' : 0,
        'body_len_dist' : 0,
        'duration' : 0,
        'reads' : 0,
        'read_ops' : 0,
        'read_us' : 0,
        'writes' : 0,
        'write_ops' : 0,
        'write_us' : 0,
        'total_ops' : 0,
        'bytes_written' : 0,
        'GB_written' : 0,
        'bbytes_written' : 0,
        'bGB_written' : 0,
        'avg_write_put' : 0,
        'written_perdoc' : 0,
        'write_amp' : 0
    }
    for key_dict in data:
        for key, val in key_dict.iteritems():
            value= float(val)
            avg[key] = sum( float(avg[key]) + float(value)) / len(data)
    return avg
```

I am seeing the error that it can not iterate across a float value.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I am confused as how this is happening and how to fix this issue and get the code working.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `sum()` on a *single* `float` value:

```
sum( float(avg[key]) + float(value))
```

That won't work as `sum()` expects you to give it a sequence. You don't need to use `sum()` to add up two `float` values, `+` is enough for that.

You cannot calculate the average like that; you need to first sum *all* the values, than in a separate step divide by the length:

```
for key_dict in data:
    for key, val in key_dict.iteritems():
        avg[key] += float(val)
return {key: value / len(data) for key, value in avg.iteritems()}
```

Comment: @heinst are you sure you pass to function list of dictionary? see question